# нахождения точки на графике, с минимальным евклидовым расстоянием до заданной

Tags: python, python-2.x

Графики строю так:

```
for actual, predicted, descr in zip([actual_0, actual_1, actual_2], 
                                    [predicted_0, predicted_1, predicted_2],
                                    ["Perfect", "Typical", "Awful"]):
    fpr, tpr, thr = roc_curve(actual, predicted)
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label=descr)
    aucs += descr + ":%3f"%roc_auc_score(actual, predicted) + " "
plt.xlabel("false positive rate")
plt.ylabel("true positive rate")
plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.axis([-0.1, 1.1, -0.1, 1.1])
plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо на каждой кривой найти точку, которая имеет минимальное евклидовом расстояние до левого верхнего края ( точка (0,1) )

Comment: а где определение самой функции?

Comment: @MaxU http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score

Comment: я спрашивал о функциях кривых...

Comment: @MaxU они же по точкам строятся вроде